# Write Junit to cover catch block

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have researched a lot, but not able to find proper solution,

I have a method in service class which is calling a consumer like below

```
    try {
        snsProducer.send(message);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
        throw new SnSException(
                "Could not parse Message to publish to SNS");
    }
```

I am trying to cover catch block through test cases but still not successful.

Here is what I have tried

```
@Test
void snsTest() {
   
    when(service.doCreate(message)).thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException("Json Processing Error"){});
    assertThrows(SnSException.class,()-> service.doCreate(message));
}
```

but this throws `Checked exception is invalid for this method!`

I tried this too

```
when(service.doCreate(message)).thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException("Exception"){});
        assertThrows(SnStateException.class,()-> service.doCreate(message));
```

but this throws this error
`Expected SnSException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.`

Complete Test case

```
@Test
void doCreateTest(){
String id = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(20);
Subscription subscription = testUtils.createEntity(sId,RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(20));
Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
manifest.setCommon(new Common());
doReturn(manifest).when(manifestUtils).getManifestWithLatestVersion(any());
when(service.doCreate(subscription)).thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException("Exception"){});
assertThrows(SnSException.class,()-> service.doCreate(subscription));
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong,
Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I can see that snsProducer.send(message) is throwing checked exception JsonProcessingException. So when().thenThrow() should be written around it.

```
   @Test
    void snsTest() {
       
        when(snsProducer.send(message)).thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException("Json Processing Error"){});
        assertThrows(SnSException.class,()-> service.doCreate(message));
    }
```

Comment: can you send me code snippet?

Comment: Cove snippet is added above.

Comment: that is not working

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Expected SnSException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

Comment: that means when().thenThrow() clause was not invoked in test method. I would need the full test method that includes mocking statements to debug.

Comment: added details in question,

Comment: How is snsProvider created? is it mocked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249821/discussion-between-doctor-who-and-aatwork).

Comment: @DoctorWho This is the correct solution.  Can you show the code that creates and injects the mock?  So basically, the whole unit test class?  I wouldn't recommend using `@MockBean` for this - you should be able to do it just with `@Mock` if you have some way to inject it into the class under test.